# ng-change with hours and datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

Im trying to click on the datepicker and get the date to do a mysql request in the database in order to visualize the free hours. I think I'm 
not using the ng-change sentence properly. What I need is that when selecting an hour the datepicker will update the hours available in my select hours.

this is my create html file:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <p class="panel-title"><span style="color:#5bc0de;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </span> Add New cita</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form ng-submit="addCita(cita)">


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fechaInicio">Fecha de la cita:</label>
                <div class="input-group date fecha">
    <input type="text" name="fechaInicio" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio" ng-click="getHoras(fechaInicio)"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
$("#fechaInicio").datepicker({
minDate: 0,
firstDay: 1,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
});
});
</script>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="hora" ng-init="getHoras()">Hora:</label>
    <select ng-model="cita.hora">
        <option value="{{cita.hora}}" ng-repeat="cita in citas">
        {{cita.hora}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="descripcion">Descripcion:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" ng-model="cita.descripcion">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">Guardar</button>
    <a href="#/citas" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--accent"> Cerrar</a>
</form>
    <div>
<div>
```

Here its my controller js:

```
myApp.controller('empController', function($route,$scope,$http,$routeParams){
    $scope.getCitas = function(){
        $http.get('../api/select.php').then(function(response){
            $scope.citas = response.data;
        });
    };
    $scope.addCita = function(info){
        $http.post('../api/insert.php', info).then(function(response){
            window.location.href = 'http://localhost/webCitas/crud_APM3/client/home.php#/';
        });
    };
    $scope.showCita = function(){
        var idCita = $routeParams.idCita;
        $http.post('../api/selectone.php',{'idCita':idCita}).then(function(response){
            var emp  = response.data;
            $scope.cita = emp[0];
        });
    };
    $scope.updateCita = function(info){
        $http.post('../api/update.php', info).then(function(response){
            window.location.href = 'http://localhost/webCitas/crud_APM3/client/home.php#/';
        });
    };
    $scope.deleteCita = function(idCita){
        var idCita = idCita;
        $http.post('../api/delete.php',{'idCita':idCita}).then(function(response){
            $route.reload();
        });
    };
    $scope.getHoras = function (fechaInicio) {
         // En la llamada pasas fecha de inicio como argumento para el php.
         $http.get('../api/horas.php?='+fechaInicio).then(function (response) {
             $scope.citas = response.data;
         });
     };
    $scope.getCitasPublico = function(){
        $http.get('../api/selectPublico.php').then(function(response){
            $scope.citas = response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

and here its my Mysql query to get the free hours in that date:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

@session_start();

$id = $_SESSION["user_id"];

$servername = "localhost";

$username = "root";

$password = "root";

$dbname = "pruebas";
// En la variable $date guardas el valor de la fecha de inicio que has elegido
$date = $_REQUEST['fechaInicio'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// La llamada a la base de datos la tenías practicamente bien hecha, en fechaInicio le pasas el $date
// que es lo que necesitas para obtener las horas libres que quieres.

$sql = "SELECT hora FROM horas WHERE horaCompleta = 0 AND fechaInicio = $date";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row

     $data = array() ;

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $data[] = $row;



    }

} else {

    echo "0 results";

}

echo json_encode($data);
$conn->close();

?>
```

UPDATE: I've try to change the date picker from one using angular and put this:

controller:

```
myApp.controller('empController', function($route,$scope,$http,$routeParams){
    $scope.getCitas = function(){
        $http.get('../api/select.php').then(function(response){
            $scope.citas = response.data;
        });
    };
    $scope.addCita = function(info){
        $http.post('../api/insert.php', info).then(function(response){
            window.location.href = 'http://localhost/webCitas/crud_APM3/client/home.php#/';
        });
    };
    $scope.showCita = function(){
        var idCita = $routeParams.idCita;
        $http.post('../api/selectone.php',{'idCita':idCita}).then(function(response){
            var emp  = response.data;
            $scope.cita = emp[0];
        });
    };
    $scope.updateCita = function(info){
        $http.post('../api/update.php', info).then(function(response){
            window.location.href = 'http://localhost/webCitas/crud_APM3/client/home.php#/';
        });
    };
    $scope.deleteCita = function(idCita){
        var idCita = idCita;
        $http.post('../api/delete.php',{'idCita':idCita}).then(function(response){
            $route.reload();
        });
    };
    $scope.getHoras = function (fechaInicio) {
         // En la llamada pasas fecha de inicio como argumento para el php.
         $http.get('../api/horas.php?='+fechaInicio).then(function (response) {
             $scope.citas = response.data;
         });
     };
    $scope.getCitasPublico = function(){
        $http.get('../api/selectPublico.php').then(function(response){
            $scope.citas = response.data;
        });
    };
});
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.today = function() {
  $scope.dt = new Date();
};
$scope.today();

$scope.clear = function () {
  $scope.dt = null;
};
});
// Disable weekend selecti
```

create html:

```
i add this to the code:
  <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
```

but dont works because when i click the picker dont pop up where i fail?
i use uib-datepicker

Comment: Don't mix jquery UI with Angular. Try to use a Angular directive or component that can achieve the same thing as the jQuery datepicker.

Comment: Where in your code is the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive?

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. Consider using [uib-datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.14.1/#/datepicker) which is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

Comment: @georgeawg ok can you help me to integrate it because i try a few times and always failed, if its possible.